# INDIRECT with column reference and row reference in different cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

So I have two cells, both referring to another sheet. One cell has the row of the other sheet and another has the column.

I tried using an indirect statement along the lines of this: `=INDIRECT("'VENDOR COSTING'!R"&R2&"C"&S2)` Although I did do a ConvertToLetter so the column letter is `F` and it is currently in Cell `U2`. `Vendor costing` is the other sheet name and the row number is in cell `R2`.

How can I write an indirect statement to produce the value in that cell on the other sheet?

Comment: I can give you the answer but please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I tried using an indirect statement along the lines of this:

Indirect("'VENDOR COSTING'!R"&R2&"C"&S2)

Although I did do a ConvertToLetter so the column letter is F and it is currently in Cell U2. Vendor costing is the other sheet name and the row number is in cell R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDIRECT("'VENDOR COSTING'!"&U2&R2)
```

where U2 contains your Column reference and R2 your Row reference.

Comment: I had my gym so I couldn't visit earlier but even I would have posted the answer post OP's comment so that is OK :)

Comment: +valid point to answer @pnuts , dont let Sid take all the rep ;p (jk)

Comment: @pnuts I think the C# tag is appropriate actually as Excel wouldnt allow to round up to 0.00000000000x etc